# T-SQL. Как организовать выполнение Sql Запроса каждый месяц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется база данных на Sql Server 2012. Надо организовать автоматическое выполнение Sql запроса каждый месяц, подскажите пожалуйста как это осуществить. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В SQL Server Management Studio -> Агент SQL Server -> Задания.
Или `EXEC sp_add_schedule` и `EXEC sp_attach_schedule`.
Пример есть в MSDN - [Планирование задания](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191439.aspx).

Comment: До кучи `sp_add_job` и `sp_add_jobstep`.